# How to use FINDSTR inside of a FOR loop to delete registry keys?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to delete all *.bak profile registry keys off all computers at work.
We gave everyone temporary profiles a while back, and we're trying to remove them now. The .bak registry keys are forcing temp profiles where people don't want them.

I have this command that LISTS all the *.bak registry keys:

```
for /f %f in (windowscomputers.txt) do reg query "\\%f.mydomain.com\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" | findstr /E bak
```

But that just lists them. I need to delete them.

And I TRIED to delete the *.bak keys off of just one workstation as a test:

```
for /f %f in ('reg query "\\workstationFQDN\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" ^| findstr /e bak') do reg delete \\workstationFQDN\%f
```

The above tries to delete `\\workstationFQDN\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows`. Even though I have `""` around the path, it's breaking at the space between `Windows` and `NT`.

How do I use **findstr** inside of a for loop, so that it executes on each of the registry keys that **findstr** finds?

After that, I need to do a nested for loop so that it deletes each of the .bak registry keys that **findstr** finds, on each of the computers in my text file `windowscomputers.txt`.

This is a basic question. I tried googling `findstr reg query for loop`, and found lots of batch script examples that frankly went over my head, using options like `tokens=`, `delims=`, and `%~` that I've read about in the `for /?` help file, but don't understand their usage or how it might apply to my specific need (delete each .bak profile registry key on each computer at work).

I've also only used one-liners in cmd prompt. I understand that batch has some syntax differences if I need to use multiple commands, like `%%f` instead of `%f`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

for /f "delims=" %f ...

(And `echo` the `reg delete...` just to be safe)

(also - quote the string being deleted)

`%f` is referred to as a `metavariable`. Metavariables require one `%` directly from the prompt, buttwo if used within a batch file.

From the prompt, use `for /? |more` for (somewhat cryptic) documentation about the `delims=` (and other) options. Or look through some examples here on SO.

---

(as a batch line) the following listed the appropriate keys for me (I can't duplicate your setup)

```
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=\" %%q IN ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList"') DO ECHO %%r
```

Prefixing "HKLM" above with "\machinename\" and filtering using a `findstr` filtered out the unwanted lines. `%%r` contained `\software\...`, so all you'd appear to need is to pop the prefix string `\\machinename\HKLM\` before that and your command should be ready-to-go.

Comment: thanks!  delims gets me past one hurdle!

now I'm at an awkward impasse:  Forgot that reg delete syntax uses HKLM *not* HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.  Have to find some way to substitute "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" with "HKLM" in every result

Comment: HKLM is only a shortcut it uses, there's no reason that it will not accept the full root key, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.

Comment: for some reason, it doesn't on my install.  I ran in to this before, also.  Has to be HKLM.

Comment: Nevermind!  I was just missing quotations.
Thanks Magoo and Compo!  Got it to work!!  no more temporary profiles, and saves an ungodly number of hours to go one by one to all our machines.
Magoo; just saw you are in Perth-- I was in Brisbane just two months ago!  Beautiful weather.

I figure this might be useful for other people too.
The entire line, ran as a batch file is,

for /f %%f in (win7computers.txt) do (for /f "delims=" %%g in ('reg query "\\%%f.lhd6.navy.mil\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" ^| findstr /e bak') do reg delete "\\%%f\%%g" /f))